# Reuse coroutine with different arguments per call in lua

Tags: function, lua, arguments, coroutine

I found it really useful to reuse a once created `coroutine`. I found a solution to that and it looks like so:

```
co = coroutine.create(function (f, args)
  while f do
    f = coroutine.yield(f(args))
  end
end)

function dummyFunc(data)
  print("XXX "..data)
  coroutine.yield()
  print("OOO "..data)
end

coroutine.resume(co, dummyFunc, "1")
coroutine.resume(co, dummyFunc, "2")
coroutine.resume(co, dummyFunc, "3")
coroutine.resume(co, dummyFunc, "4")
```

That work like a charm except the output is **not**:

```
XXX 1
OOO 2
XXX 3
OOO 4
```

It is:

```
XXX 1
OOO 1
XXX 1
OOO 1
```

So is it possible to change the arguments to the `dummyFunc` between the resume calls?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Coroutines`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.11) section of the manual? It shows an example very similar to this.

Comment: Well I guess it's not quite what I want. The functions "inside" the `coroutine` change the values (kind of intrinsic). Its not really changing variables one gives across `yields` (kind of extrinsic) - **as far as I understand the code**. I might be wrong but, if so, could you please post a minimal example for the sake of clarity?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to change the `data` variable externally to `dummyFunc` without passing a new value in via `coroutine.resume`? You'd probably have to use a global for that (assuming that even works) and it likely isn't a good idea/design.

Comment: No, I would like to (change `data` by passing values to `resume`) without making use of global variables.

Comment: That's what the examples do. You have a complicating inner function and aren't capturing the result of the inner `yield` as well as only catching a single `resume`-passed value. Look at the examples again.

Comment: I see. I changed the `coroutine.yield()` to `local data = ({coroutine.yield(data)})[2]` and its printing: `XXX 1 OOO 2 XXX 1 OOO 4` but still not quite what I want. Sorry to bother you again, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this. The way coroutines work is like this. When you first `resume` them, the arguments you pass to `resume` become the arguments to the coroutine's function. When the coroutine `yield`s, the arguments it passes to `yield` become the return values from your `resume` call.

However, the *second time* you `resume` the coroutine, it does not reach into the still executing function and change the arguments that were pass in the first time. It would be exceedinly rude to change the value of variables local to the function.

Therefore, the arguments to `resume` on calls *after* the first call will be the *return values* from `yield`.

```
co = coroutine.create(function (f, args)
  while f do
    f = coroutine.yield(f(args))
  end
end)
```

So you'd need to do this:

```
co = coroutine.create(function (f, args)
  while f do
    f, args = coroutine.yield(f(args))
  end
end)
```

However, if you want something more flexible, that can do variable numbers of arguments, you'll need to be cleverer:

```
co = coroutine.create(function (...)
  local function capture_args(...)
    return {...}, select("#", ...)
  end

  local tbl, len = capture_args(...)
  local f = tbl[1]

  while f do
    tbl, len = capture_args(coroutine.yield(f(unpack(tbl, 2, len))
    f = tbl[1]
  end
end)
```

Some people wouldn't bother with the `capture_args` stuff, simply relying on `{...}` and calling `unpack` on it. This is safer because users can put `nil` values in parameter lists. `...` will record all of the parameters, even embedded `nil`s (but not trailing ones). However, once you put it into an array, the length of the array is based on the first `nil` value.

Using `capture_args`, you can get the *actual* parameter count thanks to a little-known-feature of `select`. And thanks to the ability of `unpack` to work on a given range, even if the range exceeds the length of the table, you can effectively store a parameter list.

I could probably make `capture_args` a bit cleverer by putting the length in the table it returns. But this is good enough for me.

---

There is a second problem here: you are yielding within `dummyFunc`, and `dummyFunc` does not seem to understand what to do with `yield`'s return values (ie: the parameters to your next `resume` call).

It's not clear how you want `dummyFunc` to respond to it. If you wanted `dummyFunc`'s parameters to change because of how you resumed it *without* `dummyFunc` knowing about it, that's not going to happen.